# jQuery - can I dynamically change an elements parent? A a new element and make it the parent of a selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div #someDiv, can I create a new element and make #someDiv be its child? Basically I want to wrap a new element aound #someDiv. How do I do this?

```
$("#someDiv").appendTo($("<div id='newParent'></div>")); 
// The intent is to move #someDiv into the new container
// The new container may or may not be in the same 
// position in the DOM as #someDiv
```

Thanks for any tips!

Cheers,
~ck in San Diego

Comment: Is there any error with the above code?

Comment: nope. not syntactically, leastways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#something").wrap("<div id='newParent'></div>");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#someDiv").wrap("<div id='newParent'></div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can do anyting in jquery. check out [jQuery.wrap](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/wrap)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming someDiv is already appended to the document...

```
$('#someDiv').wrap('<div>')
```

This would wrap the element with a newly created division. [Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/wrap).

Answer (score 0):

if the newParent div is not created you'll want to use wrap.

```
$('somediv').wrap("<div id='newparent'></div>");
```

if it already exists, what you have will work.